# Calculo de Datas Vencimentos Baseado em Número de Parcelas Escolhidas

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, postgresql-11

Em uma função quero colocar os parametros que seria:

Número de Parcelas e Valor Total

Meu problema seria como gerar as datas dos vencimento das parcelas

no PostgreSQL como trabalhar com as datas para se gerar as parcelas

Ex: 03 parcelas

13.11.2019

13.12.2019

13.01.2020

Como gerar as datas baseadas no número de parcelas ?

Obrigado pela ajuda

Como ficou a Ajuda de voces

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.gerar_parcelas (
  p_data_vencimento date,
  p_parcelas integer,
  p_tipo_intervalo integer,
  p_dias_intervalo integer,
  p_dias_para_1_parcela integer,
  p_documento integer
)
RETURNS TABLE (
  data_vencimento date,
  documento varchar
) AS
$body$
declare
    contador integer;
    dia integer;
    mes integer;
    ano integer;
    script text;
    resulta date;
    r record;
BEGIN

    -- Por Dia
    if p_tipo_intervalo = 1 then

        script = 'select '||''''||lpad(cast(p_documento as varchar),7,'0')||''''||'||'||''''||'.'||''''||'||lpad(cast(i+1 as VARCHAR),2,'||''''|| '0'||''''||')||'||''''||'/'||''''||'||'||''''||lpad(cast(p_parcelas as varchar),2,'0')||''''||' as documento,        
            '||''''||p_data_vencimento+p_dias_para_1_parcela||''''||'::date + ((i*'||p_dias_intervalo||')|| '||''''||' days'||''''||')::interval as data_venc
            from generate_series(0,' || p_parcelas - 1 || ') as i;';
    end if;

    -- Por Mes
    if p_tipo_intervalo = 2 then

        script = 'select '||''''||p_data_vencimento+p_dias_para_1_parcela||''''||'::date + ((i)|| '||''''||' Months'||''''||')::interval as data_venc
            from generate_series(0,' || p_parcelas - 1 || ') as i;';
    end if;

    for r in execute script loop  
        documento = r.documento;
        data_vencimento = r.data_venc;
        return next;
    end loop;

END;
```

Comment: Você quer usar DATEADD (http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/dateadd) 
Mas tenha certeza de guardar as datas somente depois que a operação ocorrer, caso passe um dia seu cálculo da data vai estar com um dia a menos, então eu recomendo guardar a quantidade de dias no banco até cada vencimento, e exibir a data na view calculando isto no código.

Comment: Para cada parcela utilize: `sua_data_inicial + numero_da_parcela * (interval '1 month')`. [Documentação](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html).

Comment: usa generate_series: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/29989

Comment: fiz um teste com ele..

generate_series: so que ele gerou as datas com dias diferentes   fiz o exemplo colocando por exemplo 31.01.2020    com o parametro Interval 1 month, o que acontece é que fevereiro ele gera dia 28 até ai tudo bem  mais em marco ele tambem gera dia 28 e teria que ser 31, teria que na verdade sempre gerar no mesmo dia.. e quando esse dia nao existe teria que ser um dia depois..

Comment: A Ideia do nosso amigo Anomimo funcionou do jeito que eu queria... tenho que adapitar para gerar parcela por parcela..   mais fez o que eu queria de gerar sempre na mesma dia de vencimento, o grande problema é quando é dia 31  fora isso o generate_series funcionaria perfeitamente

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/29996 troquei o parâmetro do generate series, e gerou 31 / 28 / 31 para 2019 e 31 / 29 / 31 para 2020

Comment: Resolvido o Problema....   com o generate_seriais..   ja fiz a função  ficou muito bom... Obrigado a todos